# thumbnail.so taking up 100% CPU each time I open dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, thumbnails, 19.04

After updating to Kubuntu 19.04 each time I open dolphin, a process called thumbnail.so is using up 100% of my cpu. It respawns when I kill it, without closing dolphin.

I have a webdav share mounted with davfs2. This share is quite big, but it does primarily contain files that should not be thumbnailed.

This was no problem prior to the update.

It seems that the problem arises when I open a file in dolphin with libreoffice...

Krusader does not exhibit this problem.

PS1: it seems to use up that much CPU in particular when I access a mounted webdav share. Though the mounted folders contain mainly spreadsheets and odt documents, for which I have not enabled previews.It also seems to be triggered by opening a file with libreoffice on the mounted share.

PS2: persist after update to 19.10

Comment: I have a clean install of Kubuntu 19.04 in a VM, but I used the minimal install option. I see the `thumbnail.so` process as well when dolphin is running but it hardly uses any resources at all: < 2% CPU usage. I haven't installed any specific thumbnailer accessories.